# How to restrict premium features of app in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter

In a flutter app using firebase back end, how can the premium features of the app be restricted?

For example if the user haven't paid for subscription then only allow 10 chats per month, or something like this.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add in-app purchases to your Flutter app, follow this [codelabs](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-in-app-purchases) to implement it..

There are three main types of in-app purchases:

1. Consumables: Can be purchased multiple times.
2. Non-consumables: Can be purchased once but never again.
3. Subscriptions: Gives users access to purchase for a limited amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

Use custom claims and enforce it with security rules.

Once a user has paid, or unlocks premium features in whatever way you see fit, then that user can get a custom claim associated with the users account in firebase. This can be checked for in frontend as well in backend.

More details and great examples at:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims